# Keyboard shortcut to move list items up/down in macOS Reminders app?

Tags: keyboard, reminders

Items in a list in the macOS Reminders app are primarily rearranged (re-ordered, re-prioritized) by clicking and dragging the trackpad (or mouse). I find this slow and error-prone. I would rather use a keyboard shortcut.

I’m familiar with creating keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences when the command is listed in the menubar. However, I find none for this task.

Is there an unlisted command I can use? Is there some other means, perhaps Automator (which I’ve never used yet), a third-party app, or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To "move" reminder item up and down in the list with a keyboard you can use this technique:

1. Cut reminder with `⌘X`
2. Move with `↑,↓` to the place you would like to insert it
3. Insert reminder with `⌘V`